# what is wrong with this UNION ALL mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, union, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT 'Q' AS TYPE, 
       q.question AS value, 
       q.date
  FROM questions q
 WHERE q.user_id =39
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A' AS TYPE, 
       q.question AS value, 
       a.date
  FROM answers a,
       questions q
 WHERE a.question_id = q.id
   AND WHERE a.user_id =39
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

database design:

- questions{id,user_id,question,date}
- answers{id,question_id,user_id,answer,date}

error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE a . user_id = 39  ORDER BY `date` DESC

Comment: The `WHERE` keyword is used only once per SELECT statement.  Remove the duplicate, and your query will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two WHERE-clauses in the lower part of the query. You need to literally remove just the last word WHERE. The error description is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

"WHERE" appears twice.   Where x = ..... AND ....

Answer (score 1):

Had an extra where a.user_id=39.  You only use the keyword WHERE at the beginning of the clause (a.question_id = q.id AND a.user_id = 39)

```
SELECT 
'Q' AS TYPE , q.question AS value, q.date
FROM questions q
WHERE q.user_id =39
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A' AS TYPE , q.question AS value, a.date
FROM answers a,questions q
WHERE a.question_id = q.id
AND
a.user_id =39
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error tries to explain: For the second select you only need to put one "WHERE".

```
SELECT 'A' AS TYPE , q.question AS value, a.date
FROM answers a,questions q
WHERE a.question_id = q.id
AND
a.user_id =39
```